# System.Windows.Copy() does not work with Emojis

Tags: c#, wpf, clipboard, emoji

I've been trying to get copying emojis to clipboard to work in various ways, but nothing works. Emojies simply get substituted for spaces.

```
Clipboard.SetText(message, TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);
```

I've tried doing various conversions, but they do not give any results either.

Although, if I paste the same emoji to a TextBox and then try to copy it back - it works. I even tried creating a TextBox from code-behind, fill it with my message and copy it again - doesn't work.

Comment: Are those emoji's in proper Unicode format?

Comment: Can you provide an example of such emoji (that does not work)?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek yes. `char.ConvertToUtf32(upper, lower)` returns proper dec code, e.g. 128076 for "".
@Alexei, none work. Like this  or 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following example and it worked for me:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        var ch = char.ConvertFromUtf32(128076);
        tb.Text = ch.ToString();
        Clipboard.SetText(ch.ToString(), TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);
        tb.Text += Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);
        this.Content = tb;
    }
```

The *TextBlock.Text* is . Maybe the question is about how you manage getting the Text back!

Comment: This seems to do the trick. I was trying to paste text to a textbox, select it and then copy it.It still seems like a bug of some sort, because this is a hackish way to copy stuff, isn't it?

Comment: Don't know about your method. Explain more, maybe we could help. This example shows that nothing is wrong between Clipboard.SetText(...) and Unicode!

Comment: Upon further investigation I noticed that all I need to do is to call `ToString()` method on the string with emojies. Seems rather strange.